# Как правильно сделать аннотацию *args, **kwargs и self

Tags: python, типы, аннотации, code-style

Как правильно сделать аннотацию аргументов `*args`, `**kwargs` и `self`?

И надо ли делать их вообще, или всем и так понятно?

Comment: Делать не надо, никому не понятно. Опишите поведение функции в документации к функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `self` аннотация не нужна (и так очевидно, что тип `self` - это класс, в котором объявлен метод).

Для `*args` и `**kwargs` указывайте тип передаваемых значений, пример:

```
def function(*args: int, **kwargs: int):
    pass


function(1, 2, '3', a=1, b='asdasd')
```

При проверке с помощью `mypy` покажет ошибки несоответствия типов на аргументах, через которые передана строка вместо целого числа:

```
anno.py:8: error: Argument 3 to "function" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
anno.py:8: error: Argument "b" to "function" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Документация: [PEP 484, раздел "Arbitrary argument lists and default argument values"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values)

Comment: А если я использую `*args` и `**kwargs` при переопределении конструктора какого-то внешнего класса, т.е. передаю какой-то 1 параметр, а все остальные передаю как есть, тоже надо документировать их?

Comment: Если просто в вышестоящий класс передаете, то можно указать аннотацию этих аргументов у вышестоящего класса.

Comment: Чаще всего args и kwargs будут разных типов и поэтому нет смысла описывать их типы вообще, но это моё личное мнение)

Comment: @insolor да, а если этот класс из 3d-party библиотеки?

Comment: @mail если библиотека не ваша, то вряд ли вы сможете в ней свои аннотации поставить сможете, разве что через pull request на github. В своем коде ставьте как вам удобно.

Comment: @MaxU может быть полезно указать общий "интерфейс" у аргументов. Либо через Union "ограничить" (задекларировать) возможные типы параметров.

Comment: @insolor для чего вы импортировали from typing import List, Mapping?
У меня ваш код работал и без этого, пробовал в python 3.7

Comment: @Cowboyserg, не помню точно, похоже сначала думал, что для *args нужна аннотация `List[int]`, а для **kwargs - `Mapping[str, int]`, но потом оказалось, что нужно указывать тип одного элемента, код в итоге поменял, а импорт убрать забыл. Поправил.